# Using fs.writefile to create an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs, writefile

I am parsing some xml and creating json objects from it.

I would like each json object to be inside an array within the file that is created by fs.writefile. 
Currently the output is into json objects, and I need the output to be arrays containing json objects......

Below is the code where i am creating each new json file from the xml.

Any help appreciated!

```
files.forEach(function (filename){
fs.writeFile('./seeds/' + filename +'.json', json, (err) => {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("FILE SAVED")
}}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you forgot to mention what the problem is.

Comment: edited question for clarity

Comment: What is in the variable `files` and what is the variable `json`? Check that the method [fs.writeFile(file, data\[, options\], callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) receive the content in the `data` parameter. So, you have to pass the `data`containing all the array of json objects.